# Have I to split visual studio angular template to implement oauth authentication

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have a question who has more experience then me.
I have an application where a front-end and back-end services are located and deployed in one project.
We have used Angular Visual Studio SPA template for Asp Core.
Have I to split visual studio angular template into two separate deployments (spa, api services)
to implement oauth authentication between Angular Single Page Application and Asp Core Api Services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - I'd recommend separation - deploying separately can have many benefits:

- Your API requires the .Net runtime and will be close to a database
- Your SPA can use web static content hosting - and may benefit from content delivery networks and HTTP/2

I would start by having 2 folders - see my repo [here](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1):

It can be useful to run both projects together - as in my sample. But in a real world project I would always use 2 repos.